# I missed a spec of dirt in my ghusl . Do i have to redo it?

Tags: fiqh, taharah, ghusl

Concerning my question is my ghusl affected? On top of this, I experience severe doubts and waswas.

Answer (score 0):

If you conducted your ghusl and noticed the uncleaned part of your body before offering prayer, you must redo ablution. However, if you notice it after offering prayer, just pray to Allah to accept your prayer. And then conduct ablution again for the next prayer.